# recursive namespace member function definition

Tags: c++, recursion, namespaces, implementation

```
/******header file*****/

namespace graph{
     void dfs(...);
};

/******cpp file******/

#include "graph.h"

using namespace graph;

void dfs(...){
     //some code here
     //dfs(...); <-- wrong
     //graph::dfs(...); <-- it was fine,until i call the function from main.cpp
}
```

When i define the recursive function in the implementation file, it gives me error on the recursive call line. If i change it to "graph::dfs(...)", it doesn't give me error but if i call the function from main.cpp, it still gives me error. If i don't use the "using namespace graph" and call them like "graph::dfs", it doesn't give me error. But why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `using namespace graph;` you pull all the symbols from the namespace `graph` into the current namespace. But it doesn't work the opposite way, it doesn't "push" following global symbols into the `graph` namespace.

Therefore your function definition is declaring and defining a function `dfs` in the *global* namespace.

You need to prefix the function definition with the namespace:

```
void graph::dfs(...) { ... }
```

Comment: or `namespace graph { void dfs(...) {/*...*/} /*..*/ }`

Comment: Thank you so much! I was thinking it was because of recursive call.